# Database: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command

Tags: shell, ksh, aix, db2

getting the error as  Database: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.

Code::

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

#set -x

WORKFILE="/tmp/oatest.out"
DDLFILE="/tmp/oatest.ddl"
TODOFILE="/tmp/oatest.todo"
LOCKFILE="/tmp/oatest.lck"

function cleanup
{
  chmod 666 $WORKFILE
  rm $WORKFILE
  chmod 666 $TODOFILE
  if [ -f $LOCKFILE ]; then
    rm $LOCKFILE
  fi
  exit
}

if [[ $# -lt 1 || $# -gt 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 [INSTANCE] [DATABASE]"
  cleanup
fi
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
  typeset -l DBNAME=$1
  typeset -u DBUPPER=$1
else
  if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    if [[ $2 == "all" ]]; then
      typeset -l DBNAME="all"
    else
      typeset -l DBNAME=$2
    fi
    typeset -u DBUPPER=$2
  fi
fi

typeset -u INSTUPPER=$1
typeset -l INSTLOWER=$1
typeset -i PROBLEMS=0
typeset -i DB2ACTIVE=0
typeset -i DBAVAIL=0
typeset -i NUMDB=0
typeset -i DBTEST=1

while [ -f $LOCKFILE ]; do
  echo "oatest.lck lock file exists - waiting 15 seconds..."
  sleep 15
done
touch $LOCKFILE

if [[ ! -f $WORKFILE ]]; then
  touch $WORKFILE
fi
chmod 666 $WORKFILE

echo "" > $TODOFILE
chmod 754 $TODOFILE


if [[ DB2ACTIVE -eq 1 && DBAVAIL -eq 1 ]]; then
  sudo -u $INSTLOWER sh -c ". /home/prods/db2/$INSTUPPER/.profile \
>/dev/null 2>&1;echo \"connect to $DBNAME;\" > $DDLFILE; echo \"select \
tbsp_auto_resize_enabled,tbsp_name from table(snap_get_tbsp('',-1)) as t \
where tbsp_type=0;\" >> $DDLFILE; db2 -tf $DDLFILE" > $WORKFILE
cat $WORKFILE|grep -v select|grep -v ${INSTUPPER}|grep -v ${DBUPPER} \
|egrep '0|1'|while read STATE TABSPACE; do
    if [[ $STATE -eq 1 ]]; then
      echo "OK    - Autoresize enabled for $TABSPACE"
    else
      echo "ERROR - Autoresize disabled for $TABSPACE"
      PROBLEMS=$PROBLEMS+1
    fi
  done
else
  echo "ERROR - Cannot check tablespace autoresizing as db2 is inactive"
fi
```

++++++

Debug mode ::

```
+ [[ DB2ACTIVE -eq 1 ]]
+ [[ DBAVAIL -eq 1 ]]
+ sudo -u uom15c sh -c . /home/prods/db2/UOM15C/.profile >/dev/null 2>&1;echo "connect to mdmdb;" > /tmp/oatest.ddl; echo "select tbsp_auto_resize_enabled,tbsp_name from table(snap_get_tbsp('',-1)) as t where tbsp_type=0;" >> /tmp/oatest.ddl; db2 -tf /tmp/oatest.ddl
+ 1> /tmp/oatest.out
+ cat /tmp/oatest.out
+ read STATE TABSPACE
+ grep -v select
+ grep -v UOM15C
+ grep -v MDMDB
+ egrep 0|1
oatest[696]: Database: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: This code contains `/tmp` vulnerabilities that allow arbitrary file overwrite against any file owned by the user running this code. To avoid having a CVE assigned to this code, use some other, not-`/tmp` directory, or use `mktemp(1)` or similar to first create a safe space to use.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
if [[ DB2ACTIVE -eq 1 && DBAVAIL -eq 1 ]]; then
```

by

```
if [[ ${DB2ACTIVE} -eq 1 && ${DBAVAIL} -eq 1 ]]; then
```

and obviously you didn't give proper DB2 ID.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after making changes as below.

Before:

```
if [[ $STATE -eq 1 ]]; then
```

After:

```
if [[ "$STATE" == 1 ]]; then
```